# How to get the time that a value remains above a limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a thermometer which is storing all the reading data.
Example:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0aab3/9

The idea is to obtain the time that remained with temperature above **85** fahrenheit.

I have invested everything according to my knowledge and I have not been able to find the solution.
Currently, what I'm doing is getting the time when I went above 85 and then getting the next low value of 85 to calculate the difference in time.

If the temperature is maintained at 85 for 5 consecutive minutes the data may fail.
**Please**, what would be the way to calculate this?

According to the example of sqlfiddle, the results shown are greater than or equal to 85, but in some cases it was not maintained means that low.
that peak from the beginning to the low must be taken and the time is calculated in seconds, therefore, I must do it successively until the end.
Then add all the seconds and get the time.

[image]

Comment: Nearly there, but see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what is the expected result or output you want to display?  For example: 2344 | 2018-02-19 |  08:12:27 | 08:56:36 | 00:44:09

Comment: Thank you,
the result is the time in second that stayed above 85. ej
sen | s_date | total

Comment: The SQLFiddle is good, but you should provide sample data and desired results *as text tables* in question, so the question does not depend on a remote site to be understood.

Comment: please give us a sample output:  sen | s_date | total  for example, is this correct?   2344 | 2018-02-19 |  xxxx

Comment: In your sqlfiddle example; would you get the time difference between A) 08:58:24 and 08:56:36  or B) 08:58:24 minus 08:12:27 ? Thanks.

Comment: Hello, @anonyXmous A sample of the result
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0aab3/146

Comment: There are some issues on your sample result.  It is not consistent. 1) fourth row should be 13:36:09 minus 09:09:03 and not 09:05:36  and 2) (last row) why would you have 13:41:03 and 14:12:57? Both times have temp > 85 so it should not be included isn't?  Please answer my previous question (is it A or B?)

Comment: The answer would be B
From the rise to the descent. @anonyXmous

Comment: Please check my update : I took the liberty to add an ID to improve the query's performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Base answer (no modification on the table)

I could find a way around with variables and some `IF` functions that manipulate them. See if this works for you :

```
SET @currIndex = 1;
SET @indicator = FALSE;
SET @prevIndex = 0;

SELECT Q2.sen,
       MIN(Q2.subTime) as 'From', 
       MAX(Q2.subTime) AS 'To',
       TIMEDIFF(MAX(Q2.subTime), MIN(Q2.subTime)) as diff
    FROM (SELECT IF(Q1.temp < 85, 
                    IF(@prevIndex = @currIndex, 
                       (@currIndex := @currIndex +1) -1, 
                       @currIndex), 
                    @prevIndex := @currIndex) AS 'Ind', 
                 Q1.subTime,  
                 Q1.temp,
                 Q1.sen
              FROM (SELECT IF(sen_temp.temp < 85, 
                              (@indicator XOR (@indicator := FALSE)),
                              @indicator := TRUE) as ind,
                           s_time AS subTime, 
                           temp, 
                           sen
                        FROM sen_temp
                    ) AS Q1
              WHERE Q1.ind
          ) AS Q2
   GROUP BY Q2.`Ind`
   ORDER BY Q2.subTime;
```

Here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0aab3/146) based on your own.

The main problem of this query is its performance. Since there is no ID on the table, data had to be carried through the queries.

---

## Performance answer (table modification required)

After a lot of optimization work, I ended up adding an ID to the table. It allowed me to have only one sub query instead of 2 and to carry less data in the sub query.

```
SET @indicator = FALSE;
SET @currentIndex = 0;

SELECT T1.sen, MIN(T1.s_time) as 'From', MAX(T1.s_time) AS 'To', 
       TIMEDIFF(MAX(T1.s_time), MIN(T1.s_time)) as diff
    FROM (SELECT id, (CASE WHEN (temp >= 85) THEN 
                        @currentIndex + (@indicator := TRUE)
                      WHEN (@indicator) THEN 
                        @currentIndex := @currentIndex + (@indicator := FALSE) + 1
                      ELSE 
                        @indicator := FALSE 
                      END) as ind
            FROM sen_temp
            ORDER BY id, s_date, s_time)  AS Q1
    INNER JOIN sen_temp AS T1 ON Q1.id = T1.id
    WHERE Q1.ind > 0
    GROUP BY T1.sen, Q1.ind
```

Please check [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/41975b/53) for this more efficient version.

---

## Performance difference explanation

When creating a MySQL Query, performance is always key. If it is simple, the query will execute efficiently and you should not have any problem unless you get into some syntax error or other optimization problems like filtering or ordering data on a field that's not indexed.

When we create sub-queries, it's harder for the database to handle the query. The reason is quite simple : it potentially uses more RAM. When a query containing sub-queries is executed, the sub-queries are executed first ("obviously!" you might say). When a sub-query is executed, the server needs to keep those values for the upper-query, so it kind of creates a temporary table in the RAM, allowing itself to consult the data in the upper-query if it needs to. Even though RAM is quite fast, it may seem slowed down a lot when handling a ludicrous amount of data. It is even worse when the query makes the database server handle so much data that it won't even fit in the RAM, forcing the server to use the **much slower** system's storage.

If we limit the amount of data generated in sub-queries to the minimum and then only recover wanted data in the main query, the amount of RAM the server uses for the sub-queries is more negligible and the query runs faster.

Therefore, the smaller the data amount is in sub-queries, the faster the whole query will execute. This much is true for pretty much all ***"SQL like"*** databases.

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-materialization.html) a nice reading explaining how queries are optimized

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what is expected.
I would have to modify the query because there are more sensors and the readings are daily
of different days, in this case the example is from today but it could be from another date.
Conducted to production the query is extremely slow  **182 sec.**
The index you are using is (s_date, s_time, temp)
but the result is the expected

Comment: I know the query's performance is realy slow, but I could not make it more efficient without a unique ID

Comment: I am still working on optimizing this one, just to let you know ^^

Comment: Excellent, extremely fast and just what I'm looking for,
Now, I will modify the table and add a unique identification field. This table contains around 3 million data.
0.062 seconds